# Should I be able to see Dynamic DLs in MS Azure Graph API?

Tags: java, azure, office365, azure-active-directory

I'm using the MS Azure Graph API to get a list of all groups in an instance of Azure AD (actually the Azure AD instance sitting underneath an Office 365 account) but my results don't include the Dynamic Distribution Group I've created (in O365).

**Should I see dynamic distribution groups in the results of a "give me all groups" query like this one?**

```
https://graph.windows.net/contoso.com/groups?api-version=2013-04-05
```

I'm assuming I should be able to, and that either there's a problem with the group itself or I'm just missing something.

For reference, my O365 instance contains

- 3 users
- 1 security group
- 1 "normal" distribution group
- 1 dynamic distribution group

The group query returns only the first two groups and not the dynamic one.

Also possibly relevant: it's a pure Office 365 implementation. I.e. not a hybrid On-Premise instance being synced with an Office365 instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no. Dynamic distribution lists live in Exchange/Online not in the Directory - they are not accessible via the Directory Graph API. You need to use the [Exchange Shell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123722(v=exchg.150).aspx) to manage them programmatically.

Comment: Ahh, thanks very much. I suspected it would be something like this but the docs are a bit hazy on the details.